# Create and fill database from java

Tags: java, mysql

**EDIT: I am using now preparedStatement with the following code:**

```
Statement st = con.createStatement();


        st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Xbox_One (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, "
                + "PRIMARY KEY(id), Thumb VARCHAR (500), Juego VARCHAR(500), URL VARCHAR (200), Lanzamiento VARCHAR (50),Publicado VARCHAR (200), Descripcion TEXT(5000),"
                + "Pegi VARCHAR(10), Descripcion_Pegi VARCHAR (200), nota FLOAT(10,1),"
                + "USA VARCHAR (100), USA_Gold VARCHAR (100), USA_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), USA_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "ARG VARCHAR (100), ARG_Gold VARCHAR (100), ARG_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), ARG_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "AUS VARCHAR (100), AUS_Gold VARCHAR (100), AUS_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), AUS_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "BRA VARCHAR (100), BRA_Gold VARCHAR (100), BRA_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), BRA_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "CAN VARCHAR (100), CAN_Gold VARCHAR (100), CAN_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), CAN_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "SIN VARCHAR (100), SIN_Gold VARCHAR (100), SIN_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), SIN_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "ESP VARCHAR (100), ESP_Gold VARCHAR (100), ESP_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), ESP_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "HK VARCHAR (100), HK_Gold VARCHAR (100), HK_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), HK_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "MEX VARCHAR (100), MEX_Gold VARCHAR (100), MEX_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), MEX_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "COL VARCHAR (100), COL_Gold VARCHAR (100), COL_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), COL_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "HUN VARCHAR (100), HUN_Gold VARCHAR (100), HUN_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), HUN_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "SUD VARCHAR (100), SUD_Gold VARCHAR (100), SUD_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), SUD_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "RUS VARCHAR (100), RUS_Gold VARCHAR (100), RUS_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), RUS_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "CHI VARCHAR (100), CHI_Gold VARCHAR (100), CHI_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), CHI_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "CHINA VARCHAR (100), CHINA_Gold VARCHAR (100), CHINA_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), CHINA_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "IND VARCHAR (100), IND_Gold VARCHAR (100), IND_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), IND_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "JP VARCHAR (100), JP_Gold VARCHAR (100), JP_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), JP_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "KOR VARCHAR (100), KOR_Gold VARCHAR (100), KOR_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), KOR_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "TAI VARCHAR (100), TAI_Gold VARCHAR (100), TAI_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), TAI_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "UK VARCHAR (100), UK_Gold VARCHAR (100), UK_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), UK_EA VARCHAR (100))"
                );




        System.out.println( "Tabla creada!");


 PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Xbox_One (Juego, URL, Lanzamiento, Publicado, Descripcion, Pegi, Descripcion_Pegi, nota, "
                + "USA, USA_Gold, USA_sin_Gold, USA_EA,"
                + "ARG, ARG_Gold, ARG_sin_Gold, ARG_EA,"
                + "AUS, AUS_Gold, AUS_sin_Gold, AUS_EA,"
                + "BRA, BRA_Gold, BRA_sin_Gold, BRA_EA,"
                + "CAN, CAN_Gold, CAN_sin_Gold, CAN_EA,"
                + "SIN, SIN_Gold, SIN_sin_Gold, SIN_EA,"
                + "ESP, ESP_Gold, ESP_sin_Gold, ESP_EA,"
                + "HK, HK_Gold, HK_sin_Gold, HK_EA,"
                + "MEX, MEX_Gold, MEX_sin_Gold, MEX_EA,"
                + "COL, COL_Gold, COL_sin_Gold, COL_EA,"
                + "HUN, HUN_Gold, HUN_sin_Gold, HUN_EA,"
                + "SUD, SUD_Gold, SUD_sin_Gold, SUD_EA,"
                + "RUS, RUS_Gold, RUS_sin_Gold, RUS_EA,"
                + "CHI, CHI_Gold, CHI_sin_Gold, CHI_EA,"
                + "CHINA, CHINA_Gold, CHINA_sin_Gold, CHINA_EA,"
                + "IND, IND_Gold, IND_sin_Gold, IND_EA,"
                + "JP, JP_Gold, JP_sin_Gold, JP_EA,"
                + "KOR, KOR_Gold, KOR_sin_Gold, KOR_EA,"
                + "TAI, TAI_Gold, TAI_sin_Gold, TAI_EA,"
                + "UK, UK_Gold, UK_sin_Gold, UK_EA)"
                                + ") VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?"
                                + ",?,?,?,?"
     + ",?,?,?,?"
     + ",?,?,?,?"
     + ",?,?,?,?"
     + ",?,?,?,?"
     + ",?,?,?,?"
     + ",?,?,?,?"
     + ",?,?,?,?"
     + ",?,?,?,?"
     + ",?,?,?,?"
     + ",?,?,?,?"
     + ",?,?,?,?"
     + ",?,?,?,?"
     + ",?,?,?,?"
     + ",?,?,?,?"
     + ",?,?,?,?"
     + ",?,?,?,?"
     + ",?,?,?,?"
     + ",?,?,?,?"
     + ",?,?,?,?"
                                + ")");
```

**I receive the following error:**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')VALUES ('Rocket League','rocket-league/c125w9bg2k0v','2016-02-17','Psyonix, In' at line 1"

**If I try inserting the data manually I have problems too. As you can see the type is VARCHAR.**

**Edit finished.**

I am having problems with the code to introduce data from java to a table in Mysql.

First I create the table if it doesn't exist:

```
            Statement st = con.createStatement();


        st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Xbox_One (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, "
                + "PRIMARY KEY(id), Juego VARCHAR(500), URL VARCHAR (200), Lanzamiento VARCHAR (50), Descripcion TEXT(2000),"
                + "Pegi VARCHAR(10), Descripcion_Pegi VARCHAR (200), nota FLOAT(10,1),"
                + "USA VARCHAR (100), USA_Gold VARCHAR (100), USA_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), USA_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "ARG VARCHAR (100), ARG_Gold VARCHAR (100), ARG_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), ARG_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "AUS VARCHAR (100), AUS_Gold VARCHAR (100), AUS_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), AUS_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "BRA VARCHAR (100), BRA_Gold VARCHAR (100), BRA_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), BRA_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "CAN VARCHAR (100), CAN_Gold VARCHAR (100), CAN_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), CAN_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "SIN VARCHAR (100), SIN_Gold VARCHAR (100), SIN_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), SIN_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "ESP VARCHAR (100), ESP_Gold VARCHAR (100), ESP_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), ESP_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "HK VARCHAR (100), HK_Gold VARCHAR (100), HK_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), HK_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "MEX VARCHAR (100), MEX_Gold VARCHAR (100), MEX_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), MEX_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "COL VARCHAR (100), COL_Gold VARCHAR (100), COL_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), COL_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "HUN VARCHAR (100), HUN_Gold VARCHAR (100), HUN_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), HUN_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "SUD VARCHAR (100), SUD_Gold VARCHAR (100), SUD_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), SUD_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "RUS VARCHAR (100), RUS_Gold VARCHAR (100), RUS_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), RUS_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "CHI VARCHAR (100), CHI_Gold VARCHAR (100), CHI_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), CHI_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "IND VARCHAR (100), IND_Gold VARCHAR (100), IND_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), IND_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "JP VARCHAR (100), JP_Gold VARCHAR (100), JP_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), JP_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "KOR VARCHAR (100), KOR_Gold VARCHAR (100), KOR_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), KOR_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "TAI VARCHAR (100), TAI_Gold VARCHAR (100), TAI_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), TAI_EA VARCHAR (100),"
                + "UK VARCHAR (100), UK_Gold VARCHAR (100), UK_sin_Gold VARCHAR (100), UK_EA VARCHAR (100))"
                );
```

This step is correct, the table is created. The problem is that I don't find the way to introduce the data, which is stored in a bidimensional array called listaEmpresaA.

Here is the code I am using:

```
for (int i = 1; i<listaEmpresaA.length; i++) { //la fila 1 es la del header que no nos interesa
                    for (int j=0; j<1; j++) {
                        st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Xbox_One (Juego, URL, Publicado, Lanzamiento, Descripcion, Pegi, Descripcion_Pegi, nota, "
                                + "USA, USA_Gold, USA_sin_Gold, USA_EA,"
                                + "ARG, ARG_Gold, ARG_sin_Gold, ARG_EA,"
                                + "AUS, AUS_Gold, AUS_sin_Gold, AUS_EA,"
                                + "BRA, BRA_Gold, BRA_sin_Gold, BRA_EA,"
                                + "CAN, CAN_Gold, CAN_sin_Gold, CAN_EA,"
                                + "SIN, SIN_Gold, SIN_sin_Gold, SIN_EA,"
                                + "ESP, ESP_Gold, ESP_sin_Gold, ESP_EA,"
                                + "HK, HK_Gold, HK_sin_Gold, HK_EA,"
                                + "MEX, MEX_Gold, MEX_sin_Gold, MEX_EA,"
                                + "COL, COL_Gold, COL_sin_Gold, COL_EA,"
                                + "HUN, HUN_Gold, HUN_sin_Gold, HUN_EA,"
                                + "SUD, SUD_Gold, SUD_sin_Gold, SUD_EA,"
                                + "RUS, RUS_Gold, RUS_sin_Gold, RUS_EA,"
                                + "CHI, CHI_Gold, CHI_sin_Gold, CHI_EA,"
                                + "CHINA, CHINA_Gold, CHINA_sin_Gold, CHINA_EA,"
                                + "IND, IND_Gold, IND_sin_Gold, IND_EA,"
                                + "JP, JP_Gold, JP_sin_Gold, JP_EA,"
                                + "KOR, KOR_Gold, KOR_sin_Gold, KOR_EA,"
                                + "TAI, TAI_Gold, TAI_sin_Gold, TAI_EA,"
                                + "UK, UK_Gold, UK_sin_Gold, UK_EA)"
                                + ") VALUES ('"
                                +listaEmpresaA[i][j]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+1]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+2]+"', '"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+3]+"', '"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+4]+"', '"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+5]+"'"
                                +listaEmpresaA[i][j+6]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+7]+"',"
                                + "'"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+8]+"', '"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+9]+"'"                                        
                                +listaEmpresaA[i][j+10]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+11]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+12]+"', '"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+13]+"'"
                                +listaEmpresaA[i][j+14]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+15]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+16]+"', '"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+17]+"'"
                                +listaEmpresaA[i][j+18]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+19]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+20]+"', '"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+21]+"'"
                                +listaEmpresaA[i][j+22]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+23]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+24]+"', '"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+25]+"'"
                                +listaEmpresaA[i][j+26]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+27]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+28]+"', '"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+29]+"'"
                                +listaEmpresaA[i][j+30]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+31]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+32]+"', '"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+33]+"'"                                     
                                +listaEmpresaA[i][j+34]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+35]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+36]+"', '"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+37]+"'"
                                +listaEmpresaA[i][j+38]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+39]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+40]+"', '"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+41]+"'"
                                +listaEmpresaA[i][j+42]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+43]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+44]+"', '"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+45]+"'"
                                +listaEmpresaA[i][j+46]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+47]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+48]+"', '"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+49]+"'"
                                +listaEmpresaA[i][j+50]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+51]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+52]+"', '"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+53]+"'"
                                +listaEmpresaA[i][j+54]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+55]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+56]+"', '"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+57]+"'"
                                +listaEmpresaA[i][j+58]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+59]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+60]+"', '"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+61]+"'"
                                +listaEmpresaA[i][j+62]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+63]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+64]+"', '"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+65]+"'"
                                +listaEmpresaA[i][j+66]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+67]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+68]+"', '"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+69]+"'"
                                +listaEmpresaA[i][j+70]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+71]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+72]+"', '"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+73]+"'"                                     
                                +listaEmpresaA[i][j+74]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+75]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+76]+"', '"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+77]+"'"
                                +listaEmpresaA[i][j+78]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+79]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+80]+"', '"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+81]+"'"
                                +listaEmpresaA[i][j+82]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+83]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+84]+"', '"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+85]+"'"
                                +listaEmpresaA[i][j+86]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+87]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+88]+"', '"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+89]+"'"
                                +listaEmpresaA[i][j+90]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+91]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+92]+"', '"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+93]+"'"
                                +listaEmpresaA[i][j+94]+"','"+listaEmpresaA[i][j+95]+"'"        
                                + ")");
                    }
                }
```

Could be a little bit messy but I haven't found any other way to do it.

I would appreciate if you could give me some tips or point at the error(s). There is no error in the execution.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Use a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

Comment: ... And a method to set the parameter from your array.

Comment: PS : Why `for (int j=0; j<1; j++) {`

Comment: @AndyTurner where should I use `PreparedStatement`?

Comment: In place of your hand-built SQL query. [Or else...](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: @AxelH Is to control the index of the bidimensional array, I suppose that there is a better way to do the same, maybe with a for-each.

Comment: Well, you will always have `j = 0` in this example. This will not prevent you to go outside the array bound if one row as not 95 cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be simply done with a `PreparedStatement`.

This is usefull to prevent SQL injection and will be more performant if you execute the same query.

First, prepare your statement using `?` to specify the place of the parameter outside the loop.

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.preparedStatement(
      "insert into MY_TABLE (A,B,C,D) values (?,?,?,?)"
):
```

This will pre-compile the query. Then you just need to set the values using the setter provided (depending on the type) in your loop for each instance

```
ps.setString(1, instance.getA());
ps.setString(2, instance.getB());
ps.setString(3, instance.getC());
ps.setString(4, instance.getD());
```

**!! The index is 1-based !!!**

Of course, here you should use a loop on the data array to set the values

And you just need to execute this statement with `PreparedStatement.execute()`. You can reuse the same statement over and over (in your loop), just clear the parameter to be safe.

This would look like :

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.preparedStatement(
  "INSERT INTO Xbox_One (Juego, URL, Publicado, Lanzamiento, Descripcion, "
            ..... + ") VALUES (?,?,?,?,? .... )";
);

for(String[] array : listaEmpresaA){
    for(int i = 0; i < 95; ++i){ //Careful to an arrayoutofbounds exception, but every parameter MUST BE SET
        ps.setString(i+1, array[i]); //Can't be null, if so, must use setNull(i+1);
    }
    ps.execute();
}
```

EDIT :

The error you get come from the query you have write. By printing the `String` you used, I get this

```
INSERT INTO Xbox_One (
    Juego, URL, Lanzamiento, ... , UK_sin_Gold, UK_EA)) 
VALUES (
    ?,?,?, ... ,?,?)
```

Then you see that you have two parenthesis before before `VALUES` instead of one

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have more or less understood, but I am a bit confused with the `instance.getA()`. Do I have to create a method?

Comment: @JetLagFox No, this was just an example to show that the first parameter was the one called `A` in my query, the second `B`. But you simply used your array here. You either write 95 line (one per cell) or use a loop to set those value (much better ;) )

Comment: @JetLagFox, I have written a quick example

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time!! I'm trying with your example, I have tried doing it myself but with no result. Let's see if now runs. Thanks again!

Comment: I have been trying to run the code but it keeps just creating the table in the database but not inserting data. I have been thinking that could be because the first column is an ID, so the type of the data is Integer. ID is auto-increment but I don't know if I have to specify it on the two for conditionals. In that case it should be `ps.setInt(i+1,i+1);`. I'm not sure what it is happening.

Comment: @jetlag An auto increment field should not be set If you don't need to. So simply remove the ID from the values (and the ?). As for the rest, you could edit the question to show the code you have.

Comment: I have been trying to do with your example but I keep having problems. Is it recommended using "preparedStatement? With the method I was using I'm able to introduce some data, but I have problems with some characters (like  ' and those things, even I replace them before introducing the data...).

Comment: I have edited the first message with the new code and the error.

Comment: @JetLagFox check the edit I have made, you simply have a syntax problem in your query. It is always good to print the String to see the result in that kind of huge query